# Strange issue in Production server related to sessions

Tags: session

we have deployed our web application in production environment. everything use to work very fine on development machine but when it is deployed to production, it started behaving strangely.

if i open one form that uses webpart which has session variable in a code, gets null value sometimes and sometimes it doesn't. 
Production server has 10 servers(2 WFE,2APP,6Search).

I also enabled session in web.config through powershell. Please help

Comment: can you share the error you are getting and also check the ULS logs & event log

Comment: sorry but i dont have that much visibility of the error from logs yet. but do you see any issue?

Comment: then it is very hard to give you direction, because this error is very much generic,without extra loggin its very hard

Comment: can load balancer be a problem ?

Comment: becuase you have two WFE, what i am thinking one of 2 is bad.